# Bring content of FrameLayout to front

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have this activity layout where I have a header (`RelativeLayout`), content (`FrameLayout`) and a footer (RelativeLayout) all inside a `LinearLayout` (please refer to the attached screenshot below) :

[image]

The problem is that sometimes when content (which is actually a `Fragment`) is large enough, it gets clipped by the footer (e.g. in the attached image one can see that some button are being clipped). I have tried setting the background of footer layout to transparent (via xml and via code as well), calling the `FrameLayout.bringToFront()` method but nothing seems to work!

Pasted below is the layout xml I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".BatwaSelectLanguage" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layoutHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imBatwa"
            android:layout_width="209dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/batwa" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spLang"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:prompt="@string/english" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSelectLanguage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spLang"
            android:drawablePadding="30dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/line"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/select_your_language"
            android:textColor="@color/tvWhite"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tvSizeSelectLang" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layoutFooter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imNFC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/nfcimg"
            android:src="@drawable/nfc" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imNadra"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="00dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/nadra"
            android:src="@drawable/nadralogo" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```